# How to filter numeric values by their decimal values?

Tags: r

I need to filter a numeric variable by the value of its decimals i.e. Selecting 19.00 and not 19.53.
I only want to select numbers with a decimal value of .00.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the decimal part, compare and subset

```
x <- c(19.00, 19.53, 18.000, 13.98)
x[x %% 1 == 0]
#[1] 19 18
```

where

```
x %% 1 #returns
#[1] 0.00 0.53 0.00 0.98
```